# append button title to array?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an empty array, and I have `@IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton)` with 25 different buttons attached to this func. how can I write the code for appending a button title to the array, when pressed?

someArray.append = (this part that I can't figure out?)

Since I don't know which button/buttons will be pressed I can't just write `someArray.append = ("buttonTitle")`

(ive googled and searched in here for hours, but I can't find the solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if let title = sender.title(for: sender.state) {
   someArray.append(title)
}
```

Comment: Your answer led me to this: ```someArray.append(sender.title(for: .normal)!)``` which works as well !  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For multiple `UIButtons` with single `IBOutlet Action` you can add `tags` for each `UIButton`.

So if you've used StoryBoard for UIButtons, so when you click on single UIButton - navigate to `Attribute Inspector` & add `tag` to each button. As shown in below fig.1.0

I've set all UIButtons with different title & tags.

Once you set tags, for all buttons, then programmatically you can identify which button is clicked via single - `onClick` function.

```
 @IBAction func Click(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let title = sender.title(for: sender.state){
            print(title)
            

//Here we are identifying which button is pressed. If I pressed UIButton.tag = 1 then I'm just printing it's title, else appending UIButton value in array.

            if sender.tag == 1 { 
                print(sender.title(for: sender.state))
            }
            else{
                 self.someArray.append(title)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

So, in this way you can identify all your UIButton actions within a single event action.

Comment: oh! I did it differently, but this method makes much more sense to me and would have saved me days of headache! I will definitely use this for the next part! thanks for the great explanation !

Comment: Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnoutlet: UIButton!

if let title = btnoutlet.currentTitle {
    someArray.append(title)
}
```